# SwiftUI - hex to color not correct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have written one extension for converting hex to Color. Have added breakpoints to check if r,g,b values are correct or not. Everything seems okay, but when I initialize color, it is not the same as the hex value I have provided.

```
extension Color {

    init(hexColor: String) {
        // Trim all characters excepts Alphanumerics
        let hex = hexColor.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        let hexNumber = Int(hex, radix: 16) ?? 0
        let redColor: Double = Double((hexNumber >> 16) & 0xFF)
        let greenColor: Double = Double((hexNumber >> 8) & 0xFF)
        let blueColor: Double = Double((hexNumber >> 0) & 0xFF)
        self.init(.sRGB, red: redColor, green: greenColor, blue: blueColor, opacity: 1)
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init and color space used accepts 0...1 color values. Divide by 255.

Comment: . Thanks for help.

Comment: Klutzes think alike? I did that before, too, in my color blindness app.

Comment: Also... FYI... the Int() conversion does not apply the rounding rules you might expect. You may need to manually specify rounding up from 0.5 to achieve white consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
extension Color {
    init(hexColor: String) {
        // Trim all characters excepts Alphanumerics
        let hex = hexColor.filter(\.isHexDigit)
        let hexNumber = Int(hex, radix: 16) ?? 0
        let redColor: Double = Double((hexNumber >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255
        let greenColor: Double = Double((hexNumber >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255
        let blueColor: Double = Double((hexNumber >> 0) & 0xFF) / 255
        self.init(.sRGB, red: redColor, green: greenColor, blue: blueColor, opacity: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Double conforms to ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral. So initializing a Double is pointless. `255` is enough

Comment: `let hex = hexColor.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)` doesnt make any sense Hexa only uses 0...9 and A...F. If you want to keep only hexa digits of your string you should filter all characters that are hexa digit `"abcdef0123456789xyz".filter(\.isHexDigit)  // "abcdef0123456789"`